# AWS opsworks custom layer disable built in chef recipes

Tags: chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I want to create a custom layer with custom chef recipes, but I don't want to include the built-in chef recipes which installs mysql etc. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

On : Chef 11.10 Stack. Unless you are using a MySQL layer in the same stack, it wont install . Ref [opsworks recipe](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/mysql/recipes/client.rb)

On : Older Stacks :
You need to modify the mysql recipes and alter this behaviour by modifying the specific client recipe. Just not a great idea since you may miss out on mysql improvements that the AWS team might make.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent the AWS built-in recipes from running. OpsWorks runs these recipes in a separate Chef run. Custom cookbooks are loaded only after that Chef run concludes.

You can create a Custom Layer, which will minimize the built-in recipes that are included. Prevent OpsWorks from using its built-in mysql recipe by NOT associating any RDS or other database resource with the Stack.

The best you can do is to use a Custom Layer with a cookbook I created called tabula-rasa. This cookbook  allows you to run any recipes in an isolated environment, preventing the built-in OpsWorks cookbooks from clashing with community cookbooks of the same name. https://github.com/shlomoswidler/tabula_rasa This doesn't prevent the OpsWorks built-in recipes from running, but it's the closest we can get in OpsWorks today.